# Html.ActionLink dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dropdown list and a link next to the dropdown list. When the button is clicked, I want an action to be invoked on the controller so I can download my file by the `SelectedFileId` selected in the dropdown list. The problem is, when I view the link url in the console, it is only

```
http://localhost/Download/DownloadFileById
```

Which isn't including my parameter. I assume that is because `Model.SelectedFileId` is null when the html is generated. Is there a way I can get that URL to be dynamic and change whenever I change the dropdown?

My code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileId, Model.FileIds)
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", 
                 "DownloadFileById", 
                 "Download", 
                 new { fileId = Model.SelectedFileId })
```

Comment: Why not just use a different method that looks at a model for the ID?  You don't need to use JS here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to be able to select an item in the drop down list and pass that value as a parameter to your server side action.

That wont work without javascript. Setting Model.SelectedFileId will only set the FileId value at the time the page was rendered. After that it is all client side, which means you will need javascript.

The easiest thing to do is a simple javascript method. Instead of using an ActionLink, create a basic html link or button, and give it an onclick handler.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedFileId, Model.FileIds, new {id = "FileDownloadList"}) //Give this an id so you can select it later. Also assuming FileIds is a SelectList.
<input type=button onclick="DownloadFile" value="Download File"/>
```

Then you need to write the javascript, which takes the selected id and sends it to your action method server side. I am not going to use ajax because I don't think you can just download a file using ajax. You can, however, do what the ActionLink would have done and direct the browser to your file.

```
function DownloadFile(){
   var fileID = $("#FileDownloadList").val(); //Get selected FileID
   window.location = "http://localhost/Download/DownloadFileById?fileId=" + fileId; //Redirect to file. I am using the full path, but you could use a relative path.
}
```

This should perform the same action as the ActionLink, but dynamically select whatever value you have in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong overload for `ActionLink`.  You're using [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

which looks like

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

but you want [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), which would look like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", 
             "DownloadFileById", 
             "Download", 
             new { fileId = Model.SelectedFileId },
             null)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter fileId`

Comment: your Model.SelectedFileId is not going to get updated, if it's null when loading the view, then that's what it is.  Use jquery to form the ajax call.

Comment: When my ajax call returns, how would I download the file through jquery? My Action return is `return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(file), "text/csv", "File.csv");`